# regarding the array indexing in numpy in a given example

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

The following example is about index array

```
import numpy as np
labels = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4])
image = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
              [2, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 0, 3, 0, 4]])
```

And the labels[image] gives the following result

```
 array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4]])
```

I am not clear how does this, i.e., labels[image] works? Thanks.

Comment: Try with `labels=np.array([5,6,7,8,9])`. That should be easier to understand.

Comment: Read here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

Answer (score 0):

This is called fancy indexing. The result of labels[image] is a new numpy array that contains elements from labels array that are selected according to the indices specified by your indexing array image. The dimensions of your new array is the same as the dimensions of your indexing array, which is 3-by-5 in your case. This example would make it easier to understand:

```
labels = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
image = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                  [2, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                  [1, 0, 3, 0, 4]])
labels[image]
```

This results:

```
array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['b', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'e']])
```

Note that I added element 'f' in the labels just to show that it's never called by the indexing array (image).